# How can I make my extensive web surfing secure?

Tags: web-browser

First and foremost, I'm not asking for a software recommendation. I need a direction in which I should start moving.

I often need to search the internet and open many tabs in my browser. Sometimes I just don't have time to think if some particular site might be malicious.

I never save any pages, I merely copy some text from them.

How should I go about making this activity safe? What is the best way to make my web surfing 100% or at least 99% safe?

To sum it up:

- I only need this solution for surfing, i.e using browsers
- I'm on Win 7 64 bit
- I'd prefer the simplest possible mechanics (for example, starting a virtual machine would probably be an overkill)

Comment: If your question is closed, that doesn't mean "Just make it again". What do you think will happen this time? It'll get closed again.

Comment: This is a word-for-word copy. I have explained why your previous question's edit was also not going to work here.

Comment: Agree with MechMK1 and schroeder.  It would help if you explained what type of attack it is that you are trying to mitigate.